# Hex replace with longer string in ELF binary?

Tags: c, linux, hex

I can replace a string inside an ELF binary if it has smaller or equal length but a segfault happens when replacing with a longer string. Why does it segfault? What other things must be changed so it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can replace a string inside an ELF binary if it is less than or equal length

Depending on whether you are talking about a fully linked binary (`ET_EXEC` or `ET_DYN`) or an object file (`ET_REL`), your statement above may or may not be correct.

You can't safely edit a string in `.dynstr` section of a fully-linked binary, because doing so would corrupt the dynamic symbol hashtable.

> but a segfault happens when replacing with a longer string.

What did you expect? An ELF binary contains structured data. If you corrupt the structure of that data, you should expect *all kinds* of problems. You are lucky that you've got a segfault. It could have been much worse (e.g. it could have silently corrupted the data you write on disk).

Comment: It's not clear whether OP's replacement is in the symbol table or just the text/data.